# React Native Text Input does not shrink in width after a certain amount on Web

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-web

So I have been building a Registration Page for my project, there are three InputTexts in a row, each inputtext has a `flex:1` so that they fill up the screen accordingly. It works as intended on ipads, iphones and android devices but on web after shrinking the  browser (like a phones width) the InputTexts just refuse to shrink any further.

I have included the screengrabs from the Browser(Current Behaviour on Web)  and also from my ipad and android (Current and Intended Behaviour)

**Browser (Current Behaviour On Web)**
[image: Browser]

**Ipad And Android(Current & Intended Behaviour)**
[image: Android]

[image: Ipad]

**Here is my Registration.js**

```
.....More Code For Other Things

return (
<LinearGradient
            colors={[colors.backgroundStart, colors.backgroundEnd]}
            start={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.5 }}
            style={styles.container}
        >
            <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
            <AppScreen>
                <View style={styles.headingContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.heading}>Lets Start</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.subHeading}>
                        Please Enter Your Details
                    </Text>


                    ......More Code For Other Inputs


                    <View style={[styles.horizontalInputs, { marginTop: 30 }]}>
                        <Image source={profile} style={styles.iconStyle} />
                        <InputFields
                            placeholder="Department"
                            isPassword={false}
                            marginRight={15}
                        />
                        <InputFields
                            placeholder="Semester"
                            isPassword={false}
                            maxLength={1}
                            input="numeric"
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            marginRight={15}
                        />
                        <InputFields
                            placeholder="Section"
                            isPassword={false}
                            maxLength={1}
                        />
                    </View>
                   ..............More Code For Buttons
                </View>
            </AppScreen>
        </LinearGradient>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
        alignItems: "flex-start",
    },
    headingContainer: {
        marginHorizontal: "10%",
        width: "80%",
        marginTop: "10%",
    },
    heading: {
        fontSize: 42,
        fontWeight: "600",
        color: colors.HeadingText,
    },
    subHeading: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: "400",
        color: colors.text,
        marginTop: 5,
    },
    iconStyle: {
        height: 48,
        width: 38,
        marginRight: 20,
    },
    horizontalInputs: {
        height: 50,
        flexDirection: "row",
    },
});
```

**Here is my InputFields.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";

import colors from "../values/colors";

function InputFields(props) {
    return (
        <TextInput
            style={[
                styles.input,
                {
                    marginLeft: props.marginLeft,
                    marginRight: props.marginRight,
                    marginTop: props.marginTop,
                    marginBottom: props.marginBottom,
                },
            ]}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            autoCompleteType={props.Type}
            autoComplete="off"
            autoCorrect={false}
            inputMode={props.input}
            keyboardType={props.keyboardType}
            secureTextEntry={props.isPassword}
            maxLength={props.maxLength}
            placeholderTextColor={colors.placeholderText}
            contextMenuHidden={true}
            onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
        />

        
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
        height: 50,
        borderBottomWidth: 3,
        borderBottomColor: colors.InputBorder,
        color: colors.text,
        flex: 1,
        outlineStyle: "none",
    },
});

export default InputFields;
```

**I have only created this InputFields Component because I was just testing with `flex` `flexBasis`  `FlexShrink` and `Flexgrow`, none of which work. **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `TextInput` component has some kind of **default** width. You can fix this by adding `width: "100%"` to your input styles

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 50,
    borderBottomWidth: 3,
    borderBottomColor: colors.InputBorder,
    color: colors.text,
    flex: 1,
    outlineStyle: "none",
    width: "100%",
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks For the Fast Response, This fixed the issue. Sorry For the late reply, I was Trying to experiment with this myself from the last few days.